# adding remote files to a zip file

Tags: php, zip

Is there a way to add files to a zip file from another server with php's zip extension? ie.

```
addFile(array('localfile.txt,'http://www.domain.com/remotefile.txt'))
//(that obviously does not work)
```

I suppose I can download the files to a temporal folder and then add them to the zip file, but I was looking for a more automated solution or a function already made

Comment: You really should accept an answer on this if one of these helped you. Everyone likes the points! :D

Comment: Yep, totally forgot this question. thanks for the reminder

Comment: No problem! 6 years late is better than never! :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use file_get_contents() and ZipArchive::addFromString()

```
$zipArchiveInstance->addFromString($filename, file_get_contents($mediaUrl));
```

This writes the contents fetched remotely straight into your php object (no need to write/read temp file)

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard to read remote files in PHP.

```
file_get_contents("http://example.com/remote.txt");
```

Or to copy them locally:

```
copy("http://example.com/remote.txt", "/tmp/local.txt");
```

Whichever way you do it, the contents are going to have to be transferred to a local temp folder or memory before you can do anything with them.

Comment: as I said, I know how to read remote files and put them in a temp folder. I only was wondering if there was some way to do it with the zip extension or some library (just to not reinvent the wheel). But thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Fetch them with [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), add them from TEMP directory.