# How to create a ZIP file with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, zip

I try to create a ZIP file with PHP. Inside this ZIP files I want to add multiple PDF files.

My code

```
$actual_link = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$parts = parse_url($actual_link);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
$downloads = json_decode($query["downloads"]);

$files = array();

foreach ($downloads as $download) {
  array_push($files, "https://website.com/downloads/". $download->value .".pdf");
}



# create new zip object
$zip = new ZipArchive();

# create a temp file & open it
$tmp_file = tempnam('.', '');
$zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

# loop through each file
foreach ($files as $file) {
    # download file
    $download_file = file_get_contents($file);

    #add it to the zip
    $zip->addFromString(basename($file), $download_file);

}

;
# close zip
$zip->close();


# send the file to the browser as a download
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="test.zip"');
header('Content-type: application/zip');
readfile($tmp_file);
unlink($tmp_file);
```

The ZIP file downloads fine, but my PDF files have 0kb and no content....

Do you find the error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956177/adding-remote-files-to-a-zip-file

Comment: How large is the downloaded zip file? Right now, you're trying to download it regardless if it was successfully created or not since you never check the returned value from the function.

Comment: The ZIP file has 50-100kb...

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13930314/2453432) and see if it helps.

Comment: Nope...also when I paste the example above I get the error: :..zip cannot open. This format is not supported....

Comment: Btw: I´m working on a wordpress php file. But should work also there..or not?

Comment: That depends on how it's implemented. If you want to download something, you need to make sure that absolutely _nothing_ is outputted before or after, or it will end up in the downloaded file (making it invalid). You can test it by comment out your headers and the `readfile()` row. Then visit the page and look at the source and see if there are any output (including line breaks/spaces/tabs)

Comment: I had an <h1> tag before the other things....this was the error. thank you. the file is now created and the PDF files are named correctly. However, the files are 0kb large and empty....... whats that? :/

Comment: (I´ve edited my question with new code)

Comment: `file_get_contents` can return `false`, so you should be checking for that. If you server-code lives at the same location that you are fetching from, it is sometimes a problem where either the server cannot resolve the domain, or the TLS cert and/or cert chain has validation issues.